# Is there a Facebook email support?

Tags: facebook

I have a complicated account issue with Facebook and need to contact a human.

I could not find any way to get out of the automated help system and actually tell them my story. Is there a way to write them an email, or to otherwise talk to an actual human?

Comment: It seems this Q is a duplicate. However, the linked question is very outdated. Should I leave this Q up but put in a timestamp ("... in 2016") to demarcate it as more up-to-date?

Comment: By the way, I sent a text well explaining (I believe) my issue via the form "Report a Login Issue" (https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/357439354283890) and received a completely useless answer indicating they did not bother to read my message, for their solution was clearly impossible in my case. So I'm afraid this way of communication is of no use here.

Comment: That other question has an answer that can be edited to reflect the current times. Or you can put a bounty on it (doubt it will change) to bump it again